# Calculations with integers with more than 16 digits

Tags: r, gmp

I have two big integers. Both have more than 16 digits (20 to be exactly) and I know that due to the double-precision floating-point arithmetic I have a limitation in using those numbers for calculations or even storing them in variables (independent from the programming language).

However, I though that maybe `gmp` library should handle them but unfortunately it does not. One can caclulate bigger integers but the used input for the calculation should not exceed 16 digits.

Here is the example:

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz(99899999999996937503)
y <- as.bigz(99899999999996936542)
z <- sub.bigz(x,y)
```

In both cases they are stored as `99899999999996936192` and `z`is equal to `0`.

Is there any library which accepts integers with more than 16 digits as input?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As explained in the help for `as.bigz`, you need to put quotes round these big integers (i.e. input as characters), otherwise R converts them to ordinary integers before passing to `as.bigz`...

```
library(gmp)
x <- as.bigz("99899999999996937503")
y <- as.bigz("99899999999996936542")
z <- sub.bigz(x,y)

z
Big Integer ('bigz') :
[1] 961
```