# R not working properly with big numbers because of default options?

Tags: r, floating-point, precision

Seems like R coerces big numbers and cannot compare them effectively:

```
x = 123412415124231251233213
x == 123412415124231251233214
[1] TRUE
x == 123412415124231251233217
[1] TRUE
```

Any idea why (maybe a C limitation) and how can that be fixed ?

And look what happens if I convert to character:

```
x <- as.character(123412415124231251233213)
x
[1] "123412415124231247898884"
```

Comment: One way to fix is x <- "123412415124231251233213"

Comment: https://discuss.analyticsvidhya.com/t/handling-of-large-numbers-in-r/53197

Comment: some other links which might be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22466328/how-to-work-with-large-numbers-in-r , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32368555/exactly-storing-large-integers , https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32339636/long-numbers-as-a-character-string

Comment: Also try [This recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49450755/4752675)

Comment: @AaghazHussain that is not a good solution I will update the issue with some more code the illustrate my point